# Oracle SQL Concatenate string based of value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried looking up this issue but maybe I'm just not searching correctly.

I was wondering if its possible in SQL to concatenate based off the results of another column in the same row.
Let me give an example

```
+-------------+------------+--------+
|    STATE    |    CITY    | Region |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| Georgia     | Atlanta    | East   |
| Los Angeles | California | West   |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Lets say I have this table and I want to make a new column in it by doing some kind of concatenation

The output should look like this

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
|   SIDE    |   STATE    |    CITY     | Region |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
| East_Side | Georgia    | Atlanta     | East   |
| West_Side | California | Los Angeles | West   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

So the Side column should look into region and ask What Region is it? And then say ok so this is "?_Side" Then concatenate the appropriate "Region_Side" = "East_Side"

This is just a simple example, I know in this example I could use a case statement but in my actual application I can't since its a lot of "Regions"

Is this possible or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select Region || '_Side', state, city, region
from t;
```

`||` is the string concatenation operator in Oracle (and in standard SQL as well).

Answer (score 1):

Just use column and concat the string

```
select  region ||'_Side', STATE ,  CITY , Region
from my_table
```